# Show that the initial value problems are equivalent (Laplace Transform)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the initial value problems are equivalent.

$$S_1 =
\begin{cases}
u''(t) + \alpha u'(t) + \omega_0^2 \sin(u(t)) = \gamma \ \delta(t), & t>0 \\[2ex]
u(0) = 0,\quad u'(0)=0
\end{cases}$$

and

$$S_2 =
\begin{cases}
u''(t) + \alpha u'(t) + \omega_0^2 \sin(u(t)) = 0, & t>0 \\[2ex]
u(0) = 0, \quad u'(0)=\gamma
\end{cases}$$

Remember that $\mathscr{L \{\delta(t)\}}= 1$.

How solve the problem? If I apply laplace transform in both sides, I will find $u$ that satisfy the equations, but that is not that I want.. any suggestion?

Comment: The Laplace transform of $t\mapsto \sin t$ is listed in tables, but you have $t\mapsto\sin u(t),$ where $u$ is the function to be solved for, so this is nonlinear. Probably the intent of the problem was not that you would solve both equations and show in that way that they both have the same solutions, but rather that by some other means you would show that they both have the same solutions.

Comment: Thank you Michael Hardy. I was thinking the problem was a lot more complicated than it looks.
I found that $U(s) = \frac{\gamma (s^2 +1) - \omega_0^2}{(s^2 \alpha)(s^2 +1)}$ in both equations. 
Thanks